# How to handle Non-interactive Authentication for Cloud Endpoints: Service accounts, API Keys, or custom?

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-endpoints, restful-authentication, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I'm at the planning stage for creating an API which will be deployed on GCP using Cloud Endpoints. We expect many of our users to be accessing the API from within their own automated workflows.  Therefore authentication cannot involve any user interaction. Given this requirement, assigning each client an API key seems like an almost ideal choice.  However it comes with serious drawbacks as far as security, as mentioned here: https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/authentication-method

The above link also states that Service Accounts can be used for authentication.  So it seems that another approach would be to generate a Service Account for each of our API users with project permissions to do no more than call our endpoints.  However,  https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts states that there is a limit of 100 Service Accounts per project.  Limiting our service to 100 customers is unacceptable.

Is there a best practice for setting up non-interactive authentication for cloud endpoints that would offer better security than provided by API keys alone and could scale beyond 100 supported API users?

I can envision creating a custom service that mimics what GCP already handles with its Service Accounts -- creating a  JSON Web Token (JWT) from a stored account with public/private key pairs.  But would hope to avoid reinventing the wheel if not required.  If something custom is required, are there other Google services (or 3rd party libraries) that could perform the heavy lifting of the custom implementation?

Comment: Can you create a Google cloud console project for each user?  Creating project is free, isn't it?   If there is a 100 limit service account for a project, can you create multiple projects?

Comment: We want to have a single project to manage all resources (including users).  Also GCP puts quotas on the number of allowed projects so having a project/user will not scale to many users.